# Edit file with shell script that is in the same group but not the caller user

Tags: linux, shell, permissions

I would like to edit a file with a shell script which is in the same group but not the "caller" user.

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 4896 Oct 21 00:59 /usr/bin/luxus
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 4096 Oct 20 23:01 <path>/file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 23:00 <path>/dir1
```

- **/usr/bin/luxus**: the shell script
- **file1**: the file to edit
- **dir1**: file1's parent directory (symlink)

In the shell script, this is the line where the permission issue is:

```
echo "string" > /usr/bin/tee <path>/file1
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/tee: <path>/file1: Permission denied
```

I am trying to create an AUR package for the shell script. The latter is meant to be install on the system from a PKGBUILD. In vain, I attempted to give enough permissions to the script to edit the targeted file.

This is a PKGBUILD's sample:

```
install -Dm755 src/${pkgname} "${pkgdir}/usr/bin/${pkgname}"
chown root.root "${pkgdir}/usr/bin/${pkgname}"
chmod 4755 "${pkgdir}/usr/bin/${pkgname}"
```

After investigating, I think it is quite simply impossible because of security or because of the parent dir's rights.

Nevertheless I am asking you for a solution.

Comment: Are you in a position to modify the file's permissions?

Comment: Nop. But anyway, go on. Where you think the permission blocks ?

Comment: Can you run the script using sudo?

Comment: I've just updated my post if it could help. I would like to avoid using sudo.

Comment: Ok, based on your new post, everything is owned by root, so unless you ARE root, or you can run using sudo, you can't do anything.

Comment: Previously, if you added yourself to the luxus group, it may have worked.

Comment: Even with a chown root.root & chmod 4755 ?

Comment: You said you weren't in a position to change file permissions?

Comment: It works after reloging. That's why I updated my post. I would like to avoid doing it. The shell script is meant to be install on the system from AUR. In the PKGBUILD, during the install step, I run (to sum up) :  chown root.root /usr/bin/luxus, chmod 4755 /usr/bin/luxus. Apparently it seems to work with C binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said "you can't do anything".
The following post quite simply explains why it won't work: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts